# Is there any benefit to opening a file in VBA using a Sub vs using FollowHyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

So a little background - I have been using VBA for a few months now to write a program to speed up some of the work I do. This involves opening files, and at the moment I have been opening files with Autocad using the following sub:

```
Sub OpenAutocadFile(AutocadFile)
If AutocadVariable Is Nothing Then
    Set AutocadVariable = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")

    If AutocadVariable Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not start Autocad"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Else
    Set AutocadVariable = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")

End If

Set AutocadApp = AutocadVariable
AutocadApp.Visible = True
AutocadApp.Documents.Open (AutocadFile)

End sub
```

Not perfect I know, but it works the majority of the time.

I also have been opening PDF files using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink(PDFFile)
```

Now my question is, is there any advantage to using one method or the other for opening a file in VBA?

I already know that with the dedicated sub, you can specify what program you want to use whereas with the hyperlink method it uses the default one. 
So other than that am I missing something? Does one run faster than the other? Is one method preferable for certain file types whereas the other is for other file types?

Comment: I'd warmly recommend you take your "working" code over to [codereview.se]. There are several things wrong in that little snippet you're showing, that a proper peer review could point out. CR is also a great place to learn new tricks, too. If you post there, make sure your title describes the purpose of the code, and that the body of the post describes what the code does; include as much code as possible, for example it will be important to know where and how that `AutocadVariable` is declared. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is functional, as they do different things to get similar results.

The `CreateObject` method uses an explicit application to open the reference, while `FollowHyperlink` uses the default application registered for that protocol, and passes the reference to that.

Which one is preferable is up to the developer, as sometimes you want user expected behaviour ("Open a PDF in my fave PDF viewer") and other times you may not want this. For example, maybe you know that the "open with" handler for this system doesn't do what you or the user wants.

Whether one is faster than the other isn't actually that important, as they are intended for different use cases.